# Problem converting qrc file into py one by PyQt5

Tags: qgis-3, python-3, pyqt5

I am in my first steps in PyQt5. I intend to create a plugin within QGis 3.0. I would like to convert the file resources.qrc into py file, by running windows shell commands with python. However, when I execute:

```
pyrcc4 resources.qrc -o resources.py
```

The code of resources.qrc is as follow:

```
<RCC>
 <qresource prefix="/">
  <file>://Program Files/QGIS3.2/apps/qgis/python/plugins/testPlugin/icon.png</file>
 </qresource>
</RCC>
```

The code of testPlugin.py is as follow:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import resources

class TestPlugin:
 def __init__(self, iface):
   self.iface = iface

 def initGui(self):
   self.action = QAction("Run", self.iface.mainWindow())
   QObject.connect(self.action, SIGNAL("triggered()"),self.onRun)
   self.iface.addPluginToMenu("Test Plugin", self.action)

 def unload(self):
   self.iface.removePluginMenu("Test Plugin", self.action)

 def onRun(self):
   QMessageBox.information(self.iface.mainWindow(), "debug","Running")
```

[image]
I receive the following message error: invalid syntax. I verify the path files, but without success.
[image]

When I execude the code from Windows commande, pyrcc4 is not recognized as internal or external command, executal program or command file.

[image]

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You are running a system command from a Python prompt. On Windows you'd want to be running it from the `C:\>` prompt of a command window.

You may have to give the full path to `pyrcc4` if you have not configured Windows to look in the right place.

To be totally clear, here is me trying to run `pyrcc4` from the **python** interpreter:

```
Python 2.7.14 (default, Sep 23 2017, 22:06:14) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> pyrcc4 foo.qrc -o foo.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pyrcc4 foo.qrc -o foo.py
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Same error as you. One does not run `pyrcc4` from the Python interpreter - you run it from the command line. Here I am running it from the Linux command line - notice the prompt is `"$"`

```
$ pyrcc4 foo.qrc -o foo.py
pyrcc4: File does not exist 'foo.qrc'
```

Notice the *different* error - `pyrcc4` is running, and not finding the `qrc` file I mentioned. In your case, if you get this right, it should find it and create the python file.

Comment: I add a capture of Python prompt where I execute the code with file full path, but with no success.

Comment: Thank you Spacedman for your quick response. I am sorry to ask you again: how to configure Windows to look into the right place?

Comment: Edit your question to show what happens when you try and run it from the Windows command prompt.

Comment: I edit my question above.  When I execude the code from Windows commande, pyrcc4 is not recognized as internal or external command, executal program or command file. As you mentioned, I did not configure Windows to find the right path to pyrrc4.